Why does this C program crash my Ubuntu VM by terminating the parent process?
A classmate used this code to solve a homework of our Operative Systems class, but it kills the VM after executing it, I imagine that it happens because the child process is killing the parent process prematurely, but shouldn't just result in a zombie process??
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
 
int main(void) {
    int p = fork();
    if(p==0){
        printf("I am the child process\n");
        kill(getppid(),SIGTERM);
    }else{
        printf("I am the parent process\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
 


What is the parent process of main?

The parent process probably terminated before the child process kill signal was sent.  Are you running this as root?

Why is the code double spaced?

You should perror("") if kill returns -1.  Does adding a sleep in the parent process (in the else) change the behavior?

A PID is pid_t — not int.

What version of Ubuntu are you running, and what does the ps command show as PID 1?

ps -e |grep "^ \+1 "

@Dúthomhas ps 1 will do, too.

What sort of VM?

Side note: I'm curious about what the point was of killing the parent in the first place.  It terminates normally by itself, without waiting for the child, so what's supposed to be gained by (trying to) kill it explicitly?
